# Create a X times 2 table/array, pair the rows and sort one of the columns (Lua)?

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua, lua-table

I am a total Lua-newbie, so I need your help:

I'm planning to read values from a receiver sensor which returns

1. The length between the receiver and the transmitter
2. The index id (1,2,3...etc) that corresponds of the transmitter

The Lua table pair sorting is really confusing, and I don't get it.

This is my not-working code:

```
distance = {}
for i=1,#robot.range_and_bearing do
        v= robot.range_and_bearing[i].range
        table.insert(distance,v, i)
    end
    table.sort(distance)
    table.print(distance)
```

where,

```
#robot.range_and_bearing = the number of connections sensed
```

and

```
robot.range_and_bearing[i].range returns the distance to that transmitter
```

The array doesn't sort neither of the columns.
Any suggestions on how to sort the range value "v" and still get the right corresponding robot id "i"?

I appreciate all answers, but simple ones are preferred :p

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be saying that a sensor transmitter has an identity and that the sensor reading should be tagged with that identity.

I would do that as early as possible. If you can't do it when `robot.range_and_bearing` is created, you can do it later like this (assuming the index is an appropriate identifier):

```
for i=1,#robot.range_and_bearing do
    robot.range_and_bearing[i].transmitter = i
end
```

Of course, you could combine that with the following step, which just copies the table (presumably you didn't want to modify the order of the original table):

```
distance = {}
for i=1,#robot.range_and_bearing do
    table.insert(distance,robot.range_and_bearing[i])
end
```

Now, you can sort by range:

```
table.sort(distance, function(a,b) a.range < b.range end)
```

And, print:

```
for i=1,#distance do
    print(distance[i].transmitter, distance[i].range)
end
```

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thank you Tom!

btw, the transmitter has no id, I am trying to create one (sorry for the misleading question). The robot just receives messages from different transmitters and I am trying to label each received message (range of the transmitter) with an index and tag that index to its value.